# Cannot get Codemirror HTML syntax highlighting to work in Angular 2 app

Tags: angular, codemirror

Trying to get CodeMirror's HTML highlighting to work (which as I see, has been a problem to some people as well) in my angular-cli (Angular 2 ) application.

Here's what I have:

**app.component.html**

```
<codemirror [(ngModel)]="code" [config]="config"></codemirror>
<div [innerHTML]="code"></div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  code = `<p>My HTML</p>\n<!-- hello -->\n<p>Your HTML</p>`;

  config = {
    mode: 'htmlmixed',
    lineWrapping: false,
    lineNumbers: true,
    theme: 'monokai'
  };
}
```

**angular-cli.json** *(listing the relevant section only)*

```
"addons": [
    "../node_modules/codemirror/mode/xml/xml.js",
    "../node_modules/codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript.js",
    "../node_modules/codemirror/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js"
],
```

/*...*/

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css",
    "../node_modules/codemirror/theme/monokai.css"
],
```

**app.module.ts**

```
imports: [
    /* ... */
    CodemirrorModule,
],
```

I have tried various syntax patterns passing the mode as object or string, and - as you see - making sure that the xml gets loaded first. No go - the highlight is not there. I was always making sure to reboot `ng serve` after each edit of angular-cli.json.

Does anyone know where the problem could be buried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `<script src="node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js"></script>` to `index.html` and you need to import `mode` you want to use in your component:

```
import 'codemirror/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed'; <-- this

export class AppComponent {
code = `<p>My HTML</p>\n<!-- hello -->\n<p>Your HTML</p>`;

config = {
  mode: 'htmlmixed',
  lineWrapping: false,
  lineNumbers: true,
  theme: 'monokai'
};
}
```

Comment: Thanks. THat obviously helped. Seem like messing with the angular-cli.json is not require for js libs, just for attaching css.

Comment: @nuton Yeah, it's a bit problematic, don't know if you'll believe this, but I wasted a whole day to find out how to make highlighting work. :-)

Comment: I will. This kind of time waste happens to me every other day... Now I'm struggling with font metrics and incorrect text widths when it came to styling a custome theme with a non-standard font. Don't know how long it'll take. Duh. Thanks for sharing.